# Group by in Cassandra, how to use it?

Tags: cassandra, group-by, aggregate-functions, cql, nosql

Hi i really need help with this!

In the new versions of cassandra , group by function is available , however, there isn't documentation with examples of this. I would like see examples of use along with the clause where. If i had a table like the following:

```
create table mytable (
column1 text,
column2 text,
column3 text,
Primary key (column1,column2,column3));
```

I could do a query like the following? :

```
Select column1 From mytable Where column2=value Group By column3
```

What is the map that should be the grouping field with partition and clustering keys?

Answer (score 2):

You can make a materialized view to pre-group the column3s keyed by column2 like:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW something-mytable AS
       SELECT column1, column2, column2 FROM mytable
       WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL AND column2 IS NOT NULL AND column3 IS NOT NULL
       PRIMARY KEY ((column2), column3)
```

And `SELECT * FROM something-mytable WHERE column2 = value` would have all the column3's sorted, listing all the column1's for each.

In [3.10](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10707) `GROUP BY` support is being added but its pretty new yet.

Comment: `PRIMARY KEY ((column2), column3)` this is not possible due to the primary key from mytable include column1 .

Comment: its a materialized view, when you insert data it will denormalize it into the other table, keyed by column2 instead of column1 with a clustering index of column3, so you can then query for groups of column3's by column2

Comment: @chris have you any query by which we can save results of group by after creating view.

Comment: group by and aggregation functions exist in a minor capacity https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10707